# Wildfly maps DateTime to 'bytea', not to 'timestamp' in Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, jodatime, wildfly

I am using new WildFly final and I have run into this problem: when I want to persist an object, that has a field of type joda.time.DateTime, wildfly want to maps it to 'bytea' type, not 'timestamp' type as in JBoss AS 7.2. And an exception is thrown. Where can I configure this thing? Or am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Comment: I've just now seen the same thing. You do have jadira's usertype lib deployed in your war? Or as a module?

Comment: Yes, I jave usertype 3.0.0 in my war.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see, checkout [JDF-70](https://jadira.atlassian.net/browse/JDF-70): "Classloading issues on Wildfly 8 Beta 1"

It's been fixed in version 3.1.0.CR10 and I've just deployed fine with that. Problem solved (for me).

Comment: You're welcome. Curious thing I had the issue at the very same time.